# Django Queryset: Group by month

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am trying count all my `id` and `group by` month in Django.
My id field is a `Datetime` has the format "*2020-07-26 22:08:55.747424*", harder than I thought. Been looking at other examples as well without any luck.

Any suggestions?

**My current Queryset while experimenting**

```
myquery = alldata.objects.all().filter(id__year="2020").annotate(date=TruncMonth('id'),).values(('month').annotate(total_entries=Count('id')))
```

**Error message**

```
AttributeError at /page/
'str' object has no attribute 'annotate'
```

Answer (score 2):

You made a bracket mistake, it should be:

```
myquery = alldata.objects.all().filter(id__year="2020").annotate(date=TruncMonth('id'),).values(('month')).annotate(total_entries=Count('id'))
```

So with an extra closing parenthesis `)` after `'month')`. You furthermore used `month` in your values, but the annotation is named `date=…`.

You can however simplify this to:

```
myquery = alldata.objects.filter(id__year='2020').values(
    month=TruncMonth('id')
).annotate(
    total_entries=Count('id')
).order_by('month')
```

The `.order_by(…)` is necessary if you later subscript, like `…[0]`, then it will not perform a `GROUP BY` without using a `.order_by(…)`.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer Willem, worked it out thanks to you! :)